# Route-parameter contains parts of route

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a route that looks like this:

```
/foo/{identifier}/bar/
```

I have configured the route like this:

```cs
httpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Foo1", "foo/{identifier}/bar/", new
{
    controller = "Foo",
    action = nameof(Foo.Bar)
});
```

I also have a second route configured which routes to the same controller but a different method:

```cs
httpConfiguration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("Foo2", "foo/{*identifier}", new
{
    controller = "Foo",
    identifier = RouteParameter.Optional
});
```

My controller looks like this:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ScopeAuthorize(SomeScope)]
public HttpResponseMessage Bar(string identifier, [FromBody] SomeDto dto)
{
    Console.WriteLine(identifier);
}
```

If I send a POST-request to this route with parameter `identifier = hello` and some correct data in the body, I would expect the value of `identifier` to be `hello`. However, the value is `hello/bar`. What am I missing here?

Comment: The documentation [does exactly this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#why-attribute-routing) with an `int` route paramter. So either the problem is the type `string` (unlikely) or the problem is somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the catch-all parameter in the second route. When I removed it, the routing works as expected.

So, the route `foo/{*identifier}` became `foo/{identifier}`.